# BeautifulSoup can't find list elements given class

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to access the elements in the Ingredients list of the following website: https://www.jamieoliver.com/recipes/pasta-recipes/gennaro-s-classic-spaghetti-carbonara/

```
<div class="col-md-12 ingredient-wrapper">
  <ul class="ingred-list ">                                                                                                                                           
    <li> 
      3 large free-range egg yolks                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    </li>                                                                                                                                          
    <li> 
      40 g Parmesan cheese, plus extra to serve                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    </li>                                                                                                                                          
    <li> 
      1 x 150 g piece of higher-welfare pancetta                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    </li>                                                                                                                                          
    <li> 
      200g dried spaghetti                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    </li>                                                                                                                                           
    <li> 
      1 clove of garlic                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    </li>                                                                                                                                         
    <li> 
      extra virgin olive oil                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    </li>                                                                                  
  </ul>
</div
```

I first tried just using requests and beautiful soup but my code didn't find the list elements. I then tried using Selenium and it still didn't work. My code is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd 

url = "https://www.jamieoliver.com/recipes/pasta-recipes/cracker-ravioli/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for ultag in soup.findAll('div', {'class': "col-md-12 ingredient-wrapper"}):
# for ultag in soup.findAll('ul', {'class': 'ingred_list '}):
    for litag in ultag.findALL('li'):
        print(litag.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the ingredients list, you can use this example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.jamieoliver.com/recipes/pasta-recipes/gennaro-s-classic-spaghetti-carbonara/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

for li in soup.select('.ingred-list li'):
    print(' '.join(li.text.split()))
```

Prints:

```
3 large free-range egg yolks
40 g Parmesan cheese , plus extra to serve
1 x 150 g piece of higher-welfare pancetta
200 g dried spaghetti
1 clove of garlic
extra virgin olive oil
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Would it be possible to explain what your code does and why it is different please?

Comment: @wickedskengman My code is not using Selenium (in this case it's not necessary). In your code you have `.findALL` it should be `.findAll`. Also, I'm using CSS selector (so loop in the loop is not needed).